# Can I make Home folders close on click?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, home-screen-folders

So, say I have a folder on my home screen. In it I have a bunch of shortcuts. If I click one of those shortcuts it runs the program. Now when I come back to the home screen the folder is still sitting there open. Most of the time I want to go to something else on the home screen when coming back to it, not something in that folder. To that end is it possible to make it so that upon clicking a shortcut in a folder, after launching the app (or before, doesn't really matter) it would also close the folder, so that when I come back to the home screen I am actually AT the home screen without needing to manually close the folder?

Running rooted, but otherwise stock Galaxy S Captivate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but from what I am reading in forums, etc, [Apps Organizer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apps-organizer/com.google.code.appsorganizer) is a free app that does what you are looking for. When you select an app in a folder, it closes the folder.

EDIT: update - I just tried out Apps Organizer. It does close the folder when you select something. The only problem is that it appears to only allow app shortcuts - not bookmarks, widgets, etc. There appear to be other apps (Folder Organizer) that are able to hold bookmarks, however.

Comment: I really like Folder Organizer. The folders feel light-weight, and it has a clean look. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Automate flow i wrote that closes folders when you go to the home screen (not when you open an app, but it still works within a few milliseconds)

(Get "Automate" from the Google Play Store first)
https://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/36343